Mongodb: Error: Failed to create couple: Operation `couples.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I have mongodb setup locally and I created a database with a collection couples. I verified this using mongosh:

This is the code that connects to the database:

databaseConfig.ts

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/memory-box';

export const client = new MongoClient(uri);

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
    }
}

This is how I use it:

server.ts

async function startServer() {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase(); // Connect to the database
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to start the server:', error);
  }
}

startServer();

This is the function that creates a couple:

coupleService.ts

export async function createCouple(name1: string, email1: string, name2: string, email2: string): Promise<CoupleType> {
    try {
        const newCouple = new Couple({
            name1,
            email1,
            name2,
            email2,
        });

        const savedCouple = await newCouple.save();
        return savedCouple;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to create couple: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

This is the couple model:

Couple.ts

import mongoose, { Model } from 'mongoose';
import coupleSchema from '../schemas/coupleSchema';
import { CoupleType } from '../types/coupleTypes';

const Couple: Model<CoupleType> = mongoose.model<CoupleType>('Couple', coupleSchema);

export default Couple;

This is the couple schema:

coupleSchema.ts

import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const coupleSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name1: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email1: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            match: [/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/, 'Please use a valid email address.'],
        },
        name2: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email2: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            match: [/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/, 'Please use a valid email address.'],
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true, 
    }
);

export default coupleSchema;

When I use postman to create a couple it logs this:
Connected to the database
Server is running on port 3000
 ~ createCoupleHandler ~ req.body: {
  name1: 'John Doe',
  email1: 'john@example.com',
  name2: 'Jane Doe',
  email2: 'jane@example.com'
}
 ~ createCoupleHandler ~ error: Error: Failed to create couple: Operation `couples.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms


I'm not sure what's going on. It seems to be connecting to the database properly but unable to create the couple.

I tried to access the couple collection manually and insert the document and it works:
export async function connectToDatabase() {
    try {
        // Connect to the MongoDB server
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to the database');

        /** DEBUGGING THE BUFFER ISSUE */
        // List all collections in the connected database
        const database = client.db();

        const couplesCollection = database.collection('couples');

        // Insert a couple into the couples collection
        const result = await couplesCollection.insertOne({
            name1: 'John Doe',
            email1: 'john@example.com',
            name2: 'Jane Doe',
            email2: 'jane@example.com',
        });
        console.log('Inserted couple:', result.insertedId);

        // Find all couples in the couples collection and log them
        const allCouples = await couplesCollection.find().toArray();
        console.log('All couples:', allCouples);

        const collections = await database.listCollections().toArray();
        console.log('Collections:', collections.map(collection => collection.name));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
    }
}


So I think the Couple model in the service isn't accessing the database instance or something like that.
Any idea what's going on?

You are using the Node.js native MongoClient to connect but then trying to use a mongoose model to insert. You need to decide which driver you want to use. If you want to keep using mongoose then just connect with the mongoose.connect() method shown here. Mongoose will let you use models without throwing an error due to buffering. It's only when you try to query that you will then get an error if mongoose has not established a connection.
